# How to GET the Markup and Issues of an item from BIM 360 within .NET

Tags: .net, autodesk-bim360

I am able to `GET` the information of an item from BIM 360 but I am having trouble obtaining the `Markups` and `Issues` associated with it. Is it possible to get the this on .NET?

I have obtained both the information of the item and information regarding it's version. However neither has the information I am looking for.

I used the following URL to obtain the information of the`item`:

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/items/:item_id
```

I also used the following URL to obtain the information of a `version` from `item`:

```
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id
```

**Item info result:**

```
"included": [
    {
      "type": "versions",
      "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.76kuKMRdTUGQv7hdLKMf6Q?version=1",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "AAA - My PDF file.pdf",
        "displayName": "AAA - My PDF file.pdf",
        "createTime": "2019-02-14T17:00:34Z",
        "createUserId": "9KMFMLS9T2Q2",
        "createUserName": "Nathan Hurley",
        "lastModifiedTime": "2019-02-14T17:00:45Z",
        "lastModifiedUserId": "9KMFMLS9T2Q2",
        "lastModifiedUserName": "Nathan Hurley",
        "versionNumber": 1,
        "fileType": "pdf",
        "extension": {
          "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
          "version": "1.0",
          "schema": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
          },
          "data": {
            "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
            "extractionState": "SUCCESS",
            "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
            "reviewState": "NOT_IN_REVIEW",
            "revisionDisplayLabel": "1",
            "sourceFileName": "AAA - My PDF file.pdf"
          }
        }
      },
```

**Version info result:**

```
{
  "type": "versions",
  "id": ****************************************,
  "attributes": {
    "name": "AAA - My PDF file.pdf",
    "displayName": "AAA - My PDF file.pdf",
    "createTime": *******************,
    "createUserId": *******************,
    "createUserName": "Nathan Hurley",
    "lastModifiedTime": *******************,
    "lastModifiedUserId": *******************,
    "lastModifiedUserName": "Nathan Hurley",
    "versionNumber": 1,
    "fileType": "pdf",
    "extension": {
      "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
      "version": "1.0",
      "schema": {
        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
      },
      "data": {
        "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
        "extractionState": "SUCCESS",
        "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
        "reviewState": "NOT_IN_REVIEW",
        "revisionDisplayLabel": "1",
        "sourceFileName": "AAA - My PDF file.pdf"
      }
    }
  },
```

(There are more lines of code than what is shown above but these portions of code contains the most information).

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/pushpins/) to retrieve item level issues.

Basically you are still retrieving all the issues from a given container and then filter them based on the `targer_urn` attributes to associate them with your items.

Here's our code sample: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360-csharp-issues

Going forward with the release of our upcoming BIM360 Relationship Service and Markup API (stay tuned to our [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog) for their release dates) you will be able to create relationships between objects and go for a more direct approach in terms of querying for issues against given items.